# How can I connect to my SignalR hub from a different host?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that is running [SignalR 2.2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy) this app is running on `hub.domain.com`. On another Asp.Net MVC-5-based app (i.e. `localhost:15371`) I want to interact with the hub.

On my `localhost:15371` application, I added the following code

```
<script>
    var myHubHost = 'http://hub.domain.com/';
</script>
<script src="http://hub.domain.com/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hub.domain.com/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="http://hub.domain.com/signalr/custom_code.js"></script>
```

However, I am getting the following error when trying to connect to the hub on `app.domain.com` but it is working fine when I run it directly from `hub.domain.com`

> Error: Error during negotiation request.

To enable `CORS` on my hub app by adding the following to my `<system.webServer></system.webServer>` section in the `Web.config` file.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I also, tried to enable `JSONP` and and the detailed errors on my hub like so

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);

    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubConfiguration.EnableJSONP = true;
    app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
}
```

What could be causing this error? What else needs to be done to connect to my hub from another app?

The code that is used to connect to the my hub is as follow and found in the `custom_code.js` file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var app = $.connection.myHubName;

    // The getApiUrl() method return http://hub.domain.com/signalr
    // as the myHubHost variable is set to http://hub.domain.com/
    $.connection.hub.url = getApiUrl('signalr');
    $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });

    // Create a function that the hub can call back get the new events
    app.client.updatePanel = function (message) {
        // Do stuff
    }

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start();

    // This allows me to set a variable to control the base-url host when including this file on a different app.
    function getApiUrl(uri) 
    {
        var link = "/";

        if (typeof window.myHubHost !== typeof someUndefinedVariableName) {
            link = window.myHubHost;
        }
        return link + uri;
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**

I enabled logging as per like so

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
```

I also installed `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package to enable cors as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain). Here is my current configuration

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
    {
        EnableDetailedErrors = true
    };

    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

Here is the logs that I get in the console. As you can see, the negotiation fails.

```
SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url.
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'myHubName'.
SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://hub.domain.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D'.
SignalR error: Error: Error during negotiation request.
SignalR: Stopping connection.
```

Comment: hubConfiguration.EnableCrossDomain = true;

Comment: EnableCrossDomain is not an option on SignalR 2

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

Comment: @MrgGek that requires `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package which required Asp.Net-Core not Asp.Net-MVC-5

Comment: It doesn't require asp.net core

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/ please review the dependencies

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Cors (>= 5.0.0) - this is not asp.net core
Microsoft.Owin (>= 3.1.0)
Owin (>= 1.0.0)

Comment: Got you. I am trying it now.

Comment: I was able to install that package and enabled Cors as per the document. However, I am still unable to connect to the hub. Please check my updated question

Comment: You need to declare client-side functions before starting the hub

Comment: that just got rid of `No hubs have been subscribed to.  The client will not receive data from hubs.` log and showed that a `Client subscribed to 'myHubName`.` But still getting the `Error: Error during negotiation request` error. I updated my question after this update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160965/discussion-between-mike-a-and-mrg-gek).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem finally.

I had html base tag in my layout which was causing the problem.

I removed

and my problem was solved!